# implement build of Shopify-App-Temp-PHP on live show Missing host query argument

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

Got error when implement build on live AWS EC2

Missing host query argument
Your app can only load if the URL has a host argument. Please ensure that it is set, or access your app using the Partners Dashboard Test your app feature

ISSUE SUMMERY

Trying to deploy Shopify-App-Temp-PHP on AWS ec2 but getting error Missing host query argument

What I Try to Do
Setup Apache2 on AWS EC2 instance and

```
git clone git-url-of-my-app
```

in root directory run

```
npm install
cd web
```

update .env as per requirements then run

```
composer install
php artisan migrate --seed
cd ..
npm run build
```

also change root path to

/var/www/html/app/web/public

then got error

Missing host query argument
Your app can only load if the URL has a host argument. Please ensure that it is set, or access your app using the Partners Dashboard Test your app feature

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eUxF.png)

please guide if anyone solve this issue before.

if possible please share some helping guide to deploy shopify-app-temp-php app on AWS.

Thanks.